# Get all VLAN interfaces of a real interface

Tags: networking, linux-device-driver, vlan

I create a VLAN interface with the following command in shell.

```
ip link add link port-1 name port-1.10 type vlan id 10
```

and I want my netdevice driver kernel module be able to get all the information of VLAN interfaces I create including vlan ID.

What struct member should I look into or kernel code should I call?

I tried to look into linux/netdevice.h and got no idea what function should I call.
I wish there is a list of VLAN interfaces of a real interface for me to look up.

Comment: Check this link I think you might find your answer
https://askubuntu.com/questions/495969/how-can-i-see-which-vlan-a-virtual-network-interface-is-assigned-to

Comment: VLAN interfaces are real interfaces. I think you mean to distinguish between physical and logical (virtual) interfaces. Both types are real interfaces and can be used.

Comment: Thank you both for giving me the idea and the right directions to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I do not need to check ALL the VLAN interfaces that I've created. Instead I check whether the VLAN tag in the packet has a match VLAN interface with the following code.

```c
struct net_device *vlan_dev;
...
vlan_dev = __vlan_find_dev_deep_rcu(dev, svlan ? htons(ETH_P_8021AD) : htons(ETH_P_8021Q), vid);
if (vlan_dev == NULL) {
    /* There's no match VLAN interface. */
    ...
}
/* There's a match VLAN interface */
...
```